# difference between Attached Property and Dependency property?

Tags: wpf

I am not getting the difference given at various forums.
Give some real time definition so that i can never confuse.

Most of the places only copy paste.
 only confusing or mess with each other.

Comment: Please see my old [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963221/behavior-of-dependencyproperty-with-regards-to-multiple-frameworkelement-instanc/16966727#16966727), maybe help.